# Does the 3/8 attack effect created by Lord Jaraxxus count as a weapon?

Tags: hearthstone

I was fighting a Warlock who used L.J. and did not have the opportunity to figure out.

I was wondering the following, all of which could be answered with the answer to the title question.

- Do effect such as Acidic Swamp Ooze and Harrison Jones destroy the 3/8 attack created by Lord Jaraxxus?
- Do pirates interact with the 3/8 attack as if it were a weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that counts as a weapon. Specifically the weapon is a card named "[Blood Fury](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Blood_Fury)."

[image]

If the "weapon circle" is filled up, it counts as a weapon. Anything expressed in the format attack/durability is a weapon, the other effects that can give your hero an attack last a single turn and are just expressed as "x damage till end of turn"